# Is there a type of rotary positive displacement pump that can pump hot exhaust gases?

Tags: pumps, turbines

Is there a type of rotary positive displacement pump that can pump hot exhaust gases (~900°C), that is,  not requiring lubrication that would otherwise be burnt off?

Comment: The piston engine has an exhaust stroke that pushes the expanding gases.

Comment: Does not a turbocharger fit the bill? I realize it's not a positive displacement device, but it certainly can handle the temperatures.

Comment: Im trying to make an analogue of a gas turbine for land vehicles that uses positive displacement pumps to vastly improve throttle reponse. Piston pumps offer of too low of a flowrate to offer increased power density compares to a piston engine

Comment: PD pumps are used to force air in, not to pull air out.  Look up induced draft fans, maybe with a controlled damper inlet?

Comment: @FrancisL. check out the gas turbines produced for vehicles. Designed to run at constant speed though - road speed can be varied...

Comment: PD pumps will still need some lubrication around moving parts. (E.g. the rollers on a peristaltic pump are still lubricated). You will need to make sure that those parts are adequately insulated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a type of pump called a *screw pump* which was once considered as a power extraction device for hot exhaust gas, using ceramic screws. This was to pull shaft work out of the exhaust stream of a fluidized-bed combustor fueled with landfill waste. This idea dates back almost 50 years and I do not know if the firm developing it (Combustion Engineering, Inc.) successfully implemented the screw pump idea.